# contraction of ideals, prime ideals & maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is more of a basic conceptual question.

If $A \subset B$ are commutative rings with identity. Then which of the following are correct?

(1)-If $J$ is an ideal of $B$, then so is $A \cap J$ is an ideal of $A$

(2)-If $J$ is a prime ideal of $B$, then so is $A \cap J$ is a prime ideal of $A$

(3)-If $J$ is a maximal ideal of $B$ then so is $A \cap J$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.

---

Question 2

If $A \subset B$ is an integral extension of commutative rings with identity. Then which of the following are correct?

(4)-If $J$ is an ideal of $B$, then so is $A \cap J$ is an ideal of $A$

(5)-if $J$ is a prime ideal of $B$, then so is $A \cap J$ is a prime ideal of $A$

(6)-If $J$ is a maximal ideal of $B$ then so is $A \cap J$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.

I did a bit of algebra here and
I think all of them except (3) are correct. Am I right?

(6) is correct because $A \cap J$ is prime ideal. Hence by the property of integral extension $A \cap J$ is maximal if and only if $J$ is maximal.

Comment: In that case $A \cap J=A \cap B=A$ which is an ideal of $A$

Comment: Right, I misread. I was thinking of ideals of $B$, not of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

Question 1:

(1) Ler $a \in A $ and let $r \in A \cap J$, we need to show that $ar \in A \cap J$.

Clearly, $ar \in A$. Since $J$ is an ideal of $B$ and $a \in A \subset B$, we get $ar \in J$. Hence, $ar \in A \cap J$.

(2) Consider a map $\phi:A \rightarrow B/J $ given by $a \rightarrow a+J$ is ring homomorphism with kernel $A \cap J$. Thus $A/ (A\cap J)$ is a subring of $B/J$. Since $J$ is prime ideal of $B$, $B/J$ is an integral domain(ID). Thus, $A/ (A\cap J)$ is ID as subring of ID is an ID. Hence, $A\cap J$ is prime ideal of $A$.

(3) Take $B= \mathbb{Q}, J=\{0\}$ and $A=\mathbb{Z}$. Then $J$ is a maximal ideal of $B$, but $A \cap J = \{0\}$ is not a maximal ideal of $A$.

Question(2).

(4) Follows from (1).

(5) Please see Theorem 5.10 (page 62) in "[Introduction to commutative algebra](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Emathieu/CoursM2-2020/AMD-ComAlg.pdf)", by Michael Atiyah.

(6) Please see Corollary 5.8 (page 61) in "introduction to commutative algebra", by Michael Atiyah.